# Passing a prop from the Vue root instance into a component inside a blade template file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Im trying to pass a prop from the root vue instance into the vue components which are located within a blade template file.

**Blade Template File:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <header-0 on-window-load="{{ onPageLoad }}"><header-0>
    <header-search-modal></header-search-modal>
    <side-nav></side-nav>
@endsection
```

**JavaScript root Vue instance:**

```
var ComponentHeader = require('./components/Header.vue').default;
var ComponentHeaderSearchModal = require('./components/SearchModal.vue').default;
var ComponentSideNav = require('./components/SideNav.vue').default;


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
        return{ 
            onPageLoad: false
        }
    },
    components:{'header-0': ComponentHeader,
                'header-search-modal': ComponentHeaderSearchModal,
                'side-nav': ComponentSideNav
    },
    created(){
        window.onload = function(){
            this.onPageLoad = true;
        }
    }
});
```

As can be seen in the blade template file, doing `on-window-load="{{ onPageLoad }}"` will not work because blade seems to have no concept of the root Vue instance. So how do I pass a prop from the Vue root instance into a component inside a blade template file? is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blade templates are rendered in the backend and returned to the browser as part of the request. However, your javascript is instantiated after the browser is done with the request. This means that your blade doesn't have any clue about javascript and therefore you can't use javascript in your blade template.

so to fix it you could access your root instance data from your component
in this case, you want to get `onPageLoad` inside the `ComponentHeader`

you could access it of course from the component like this

```
this.$root.$data.onPageLoad
```

Comment: the problem is `on-window-load="{{ onPageLoad }}"` will throw `Use of undefined constant onPageLoad` because the blade file doesn't know how to access the root instance. is this even possible?

Comment: aha you want to access data form your root instance, let me edit the question